# How to delete tags including text from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a text in $string like [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix5hwsr9m60c4ht/Screenshot%202013-12-19%2021.16.03.png).

I need to delete all `<empty-line>...</empty-line>` including the text between those tags.
I've tried do this with preg_replace(), but i'm not sure how to write the regexp pattern.

EDIT (add code):

```
<span id="chapters">
   <div id="title">
    <p style="font-family: icons; font-size: 20px; padding: 5px 7px 10px 12px;">:</p>
   </div>

   <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">NOTE TO THE READER</p>

   <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">Part 1</p>
    <empty-line>
    <p>PROVENER</p>
   </empty-line>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">Part 2</p>
    <empty-line>
    <p>APERT</p>
   </empty-line>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">Part 3</p>
    <empty-line>
    <p>ELIGER</p>
   </empty-line>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">GLOSSARY</p>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">CALCA 1: Cutting the Cake</p>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">CALCA 2: Hemn (Configuration) Space</p>

    <p style="display: none; width: 108px;">CALCA 3: Complex Versus Simple Protism</p>
</span>
```

Comment: If that's html/xml, then DON'T use regexes. Just use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php). It's far easier/simpler

Comment: Ok, how can i do this with jQuery?

Comment: @user1857307: Post the actual HTML instead of an image (pastebin it, if it's too large).

Comment: If you wanted a jquery solution, you should have tagged the question as javascript/jquery...

Comment: actually i need php soultion because all work with this code should been done in php, and then i get result with ajax

Comment: @user1857307 - when MarkB said "Juse use DOM", he didn't mean jQuery. PHP has DOM functionality built in, which is explicitly designed for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not regular enough to be parsed using a regular expression. You should use an HTML parser to parse it correctly. You can use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/dom) with [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/xpath) to load the HTML and remove the tags and everything inside it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// suppress the warnings, load HTML and clear errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//empty-line') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81035)

Comment: what type is $html variable? how i can get it from string?

Comment: @user1857307: It is a string containing all the HTML markup. You can use `$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/blah');` to get the HTML. (or you could use `loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/blah');` to get the HTML.

Comment: this code work but it doesn't delete tag contents, this is what im trying to achieve http://pastebin.com/dYHU0ggM

Comment: @user1857307: How come? It [does work](https://eval.in/81043) for me. Are you sure the `$html` variable contains your HTML string?

Comment: maybe problem is what type of my var, im trying to parse fb2 file, and my $html is string type

Comment: @user1857307: I have no idea what an `fb2` file is? Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: fb2 this is kinda xml, type for ebooks, this is full code for getting book chapters names http://pastebin.com/skX0Dbb3